# how to align these diagrams

Tags: vertical-alignment, tikz-feynman

i am trying to align the left hand text with right hand diagram.but its not working.if i use \feynmandiagram[baseline] it can be done.but if i manually adjust my diagram it is not working.heres an example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman} 
\usepackage{simpler-wick}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin {document}
$

\braket{p_1p_2|i\mathcal{T}|p_Ap_B}=
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (a);
\vertex[right=2 cm of a ](b);
\vertex[below=2 cm of b] (c);
\vertex[left=2 cm of c](d);
\vertex[below right=1cm of a](e);
\diagram*{
   (a)--(c),(b)--(d)
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
+
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}

\vertex (a);
\vertex [right=2cm of a] (b);
\vertex[above right=1.414 cm of a](c);
\vertex[above=1 cm of c](d);
\vertex[above right=1.414 cm of d](e);
\vertex[above left=1.414 cm of d](f);
\diagram*{
(a)--(c),
(b)--(c),
(c)--[out= 0,in=0](d),
(c)--[out=180,in=180](d),
(d)--(e),
(d)--(f)

};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}


$
\end{document}
```

giving me this result.But i want the left hand text to be align with the diagrams.how can i do that.
thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you load `tikz-feynman` twice
- package `simpler-wick` had to be loaded before ``tikz-feynman` otherwise you have clash between this two packages
- better is write your equation as diapslay math, not as in line math
- for align `tikzpicture`s you should move their baselines to their centers
- equation should be inside frame

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{simpler-wick}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[  % <---
\braket{p_1p_2|i\mathcal{T}|p_Ap_B}=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (a);
\vertex[right=2 cm of a ](b);
\vertex[below=2 cm of b] (c);
\vertex[left=2 cm of c](d);
\vertex[below right=1cm of a](e);
\diagram*{
   (a)--(c),(b)--(d)
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
+
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (a);
\vertex [right=2cm of a] (b);
\vertex[above right=1.414 cm of a](c);
\vertex[above=1 cm of c](d);
\vertex[above right=1.414 cm of d](e);
\vertex[above left=1.414 cm of d](f);
\diagram*{
(a)--(c),
(b)--(c),
(c)--[out= 0,in=0](d),
(c)--[out=180,in=180](d),
(d)--(e),
(d)--(f)
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you.why you put [\ .../] after begin{frame}?

Comment: why simpler-wick has to be loaded before tikz-feynman? why the clash?

Comment: i do no now why. i receive error, that they clash. `\[ ...\]` put content in display math node (i.e.: equation is own line, not in text, read some introductory text about math in latex, for example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics

Answer (score 3):

Besides the nice answer by @Zarko, you can vertically center anything in math-mode by `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{simpler-wick}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[  % <---
\braket{p_1p_2|i\mathcal{T}|p_Ap_B}=\vcenter{\hbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (a);
\vertex[right=2 cm of a ](b);
\vertex[below=2 cm of b] (c);
\vertex[left=2 cm of c](d);
\vertex[below right=1cm of a](e);
\diagram*{
   (a)--(c),(b)--(d)
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
+ \vcenter{\hbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (a);
\vertex [right=2cm of a] (b);
\vertex[above right=1.414 cm of a](c);
\vertex[above=1 cm of c](d);
\vertex[above right=1.414 cm of d](e);
\vertex[above left=1.414 cm of d](f);
\diagram*{
(a)--(c),
(b)--(c),
(c)--[out= 0,in=0](d),
(c)--[out=180,in=180](d),
(d)--(e),
(d)--(f)
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image]